# COUNT of GROUP of two fields in SQL Query -- Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgres with 2 fields:  they are columns of ids of users who have looked at some data, under two conditions:

```
viewee  viewer
------  ------
93024   66994
93156   93151
93163   113671
137340  93161
92992   93161
93161   93135
93156   93024
```

And I want to group them by both viewee and viewer field, and count the number of occurrences, and return that count
from high to low:

```
id       count
------   -----
93161    3
93156    2
93024    2
137340   1
66994    1
92992    1
93135    1
93151    1
93163    1
```

I have been running two queries, one for each column, and then combining the results in my JavaScript application code.  My query for one field is...

```
SELECT "viewer",
    COUNT("viewer")
        FROM "public"."friend_currentfriend"
            GROUP BY "viewer"
            ORDER BY  count DESC;
```

How would I rewrite this query to handle both fields at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine to columns from the table into a single one by using **union all** then use **group by** as below:

```
select id ,count(*) Count from (
select viewee id from vv
union all
select viewer id from vv) t
group by id
order by count(*) desc
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use a lateral join:

```
select v.viewx, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (t.viewee), (t.viewer)) v(viewx)
group by v.viewx
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT      a.ID,
            SUM(a.Total) as Total
FROM        (SELECT     t.Viewee AS ID,
                        COUNT(t.Viewee) AS Total
             FROM       #Temp t
             GROUP BY   t.Viewee
             UNION
             SELECT     t.Viewer AS ID,
                        COUNT(t.Viewer) AS Total
             FROM       #Temp t
             GROUP BY   t.Viewer
            ) a 
GROUP BY    a.ID
ORDER BY    SUM(a.Total) DESC
```